# Custom directive for trimming whitespace in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

I have created a custom directive to remove whitespaces from the input box which works completely fine till Angular version 7, but not working in Angular version 9.

```
import {
    Directive,
    ElementRef,
    Output,
    EventEmitter,
} from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[trim]',
    host: {
        '(blur)': 'onBlur()'
    }
})
export class TrimDirective {
    @Output() ngModelChange: EventEmitter < any > = new EventEmitter();
    constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}
    onBlur() {
        (this.element.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).value = (this.element.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).value.trim();
        this.ngModelChange.emit((this.element.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).value.trim());
    }
}
```

On blur event it supposed to trim the whitespaces and update the ngModel, but it's not updating ngModel

Comment: In angular 9 what is the issue?

Comment: I don't see any issue: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ktjqye?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: It supposed to update model, but it's not updating the model with trimmed value,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is pretty late, but It's been around 3 years since I posted this question, and the answer given by [radik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/943792/radik) is working well with template-driven forms but with Reactive forms, it is not working as expected. It trims the HTML control value, but it does not update the corresponding form control.
So I'm posting this answer which works with Template driven forms as well as with reactive forms.

`trim.directive.ts` looks like follows

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[trim]'
})
export class TrimDirective {

  @Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef,
    private control: NgControl) {
  }

  /**
   * Trim the input value on focus out of input component
   */
  @HostListener('focusout') onFocusOut() {
    (this.el.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).value = (this.el.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).value.trim();
    this.ngModelChange.emit(this.el.nativeElement.value)
    this.control.control?.setValue(this.el.nativeElement.value)
  }

}
```

And just use the trim directive in your HTML as below.

```
<input trim matInput name="name" id="name" formControlName="name"/>
```

This will not just update the HTML control it updates the angular form control as well and it emits the trimmed value on the ngModelChange event.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how we have implemented it, working from Angular 4.x to 11.x

As you will see, we are using selectors so that the directive is applied to all input / textarea elements without having to explicitly use the directive.

This can be easily changed and instead use the "app-trim"

```
import { Directive, HostListener, forwardRef } from "@angular/core";
import { DefaultValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from "@angular/forms";

const TRIM_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => TrimValueDirective),
  multi: true
};

/**
 * The trim accessor for writing trimmed value and listening to changes that is
 * used by the {@link NgModel}, {@link FormControlDirective}, and
 * {@link FormControlName} directives.
 */
@Directive({
  selector: `
    input:not([type=checkbox]):not([type=radio]):not([type=password]):not([readonly]):not(.app-trim-ignore)[formControlName],
    input:not([type=checkbox]):not([type=radio]):not([type=password]):not([readonly]):not(.app-trim-ignore)[formControl],
    input:not([type=checkbox]):not([type=radio]):not([type=password]):not([readonly]):not(.app-trim-ignore)[ngModel],
    textarea:not([readonly]):not(.app-trim-ignore)[formControlName],
    textarea:not([readonly]):not(.app-trim-ignore)[formControl],
    textarea:not([readonly]):not(.app-trim-ignore)[ngModel],
    :not([readonly]):not(.app-trim-ignore)[ngDefaultControl],
    [app-trim]
  `,
  providers: [TRIM_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class TrimValueDirective extends DefaultValueAccessor {

  @HostListener("input", ["$event.target.value"])
  ngOnChange = (val: string): void => {
    this.onChange(val.trim());
  };

  @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])
  applyTrim(val: string): void {
    this.writeValue(val.trim());
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    if (typeof value === "string") {
      value = value.trim();
    }

    super.writeValue(value);
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi i need to skip this trim directive for material datepicker can u suggest me Jacob

Comment: @Vignesh We don't use Material so I don't know exactly how to have it working. That said seems weird to have to trim a date picker input.

Anyhow, you can add a class attribute with the value app-trim-ignore (i.e. class="app-trim-ignore"). That should work.

Else you must update the code and add the proper selector for your needs

Answer (score 3):

to update input value they use both setProperty() and setAttribute()

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, Input, ChangeDetectorRef, Output, ElementRef, HostListener, Inject, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTrim]'
})
export class TrimDirective {
  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private ngModel: NgModel) { }

  @HostListener("blur")
  onBlur() {
    let value = this.ngModel.model;

    if(value) {
      value = value.trim();
      this.renderer.setProperty(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement, "value", value);
      this.renderer.setAttribute(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement, "value", value);
      this.ngModel.update.emit(value);
    } else {
      this.renderer.setProperty(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement, "value", null);
      this.renderer.setAttribute(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement, "value", null);
      this.ngModel.update.emit("");
    }
  }
}
```

example [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng9-trim-on-blur?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftrim.directive.ts)

Comment: I tried with the above code as well, it's not working in Angular version 9 projects. The example code which you shared in a link is in Angular version 7

Comment: @MeVimalkumar my bad. I update example link to Angular 9

Comment: it's working but still not updating ngModel if you add input type and binds a variable to ngModel, it won't update the ngModel. like this <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email">

Comment: @MeVimalkumar to update input value they use both setProperty() and setAttribute()

Answer (score 0):

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[formControl], [formControlName]',
})
export class TrimDirective {
  constructor(private readonly control: NgControl) {}

  @HostListener('blur')
  onBlur(): void {
    if (typeof this.control.value === 'string') {
      this.control.control.setValue(this.control.value.trim());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Directive  file:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTrim]',
})
export class TrimDirective {
  debugger;

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef
  ) { }

  @HostListener('blur') onBlur() {
    const value = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    if (value) {
      this.el.nativeElement.value = value.trim();
    }
  }
}
```

Html use:

```
 <input appTrim id="coxid52" type="text" class="form-control" ... />
```

Make sure to import that directive into the respective module as well.

Comment: @MeVimalkumar  try this once

Comment: @Hirem, be careful, this directive not work as you expect if you use ReactiveForms or [(ngModel)] -only change the "html element"

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appInputTrim]'
})
/**
 * This directive is used to trim the input value.
 * @author Hakkı Konu
 */
export class InputTrimDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('focusout', ['$event.target.value'])
    trim(value: string) {
        this.el.nativeElement.value = value.trim();
        console.log('value', value);
    }
}
```

usage

```
<input appInputTrim .... />
```